# Gnucash: credit card reports

Tags: finance, gnucash

On the Profit & Loss statement for Gnucash, it doesn't list the money that I've paid to my credit cards and loans.

My credit card and student loans are set up as separate accounts under the head account Liabilities.  They have balances that I made with an Orphan account (otherwise couldn't find a way to make a starting balance) and the monthly payments are taken out of my Personal Checking account.  This Personal Checking account is the same account that ledgers my rent, groceries, fuel, etc. that comes out beautifully on the Profit & Loss statement.

However, the Liabilities don't show up on this statement.  There is extra money left-over on the report, but this is deceptive since I know that some of this money is paid to my Liability accounts.

Editing the P&L Report options and then refreshing the view does not change the report.  None of the other reports that look applicable give me useful information.

In summary, I need a report that tells me how much money is coming in and how much is going out in each account.  This is one of the best reasons to use such a program, and it's frustrating not being able to see this information easily.